# Ver la camara duplicada por pantalla en tiempo real

Tags: android, android-layout

Tengo una aplicación creada y necesito saber como poder visualizar en la pantalla del móvil lo que se ve por la cámara de este de forma duplicada y en tiempo real. Por el momento se muestran las dos pantallas pero una queda "congelada" y la segunda funciona correctamente.

Para mostrar lo visualizado por la cámara estoy utilizando dos FrameLayout.

```
        mCamaraV = new CamaraView(this, mCamara);
        camara_v = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camara_izq);
        camara_v.addView(mCamaraV);

        mCamaraV2= new CamaraView(this, mCamara);
        camara_v2 = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camara_dcha);
        camara_v2.addView(mCamaraV2);
```

La clase CamaraView extiende de SurfaceView

Gracias!

Comment: Hola MABM. Bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Puedes mostrar tu codigo para contextualizarnos en la manera que utilizas y asi poder ayudarte? Un saludo

Comment: @MABM define que es CamaraView y mCamara

Comment: @Jorgesys la definicions de mCamara es: private Camera mCamara y CamaraView es la clase (SurfaceView). Esta clase se utiliza para presentar una vista previa de cámara en directo para el usuario.

Answer (score 0):

Intenta utilizando el mismo objeto CamaraView en los dos FrameLayout.

```
mCamaraV = new CamaraView(this, mCamara);
camara_v = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camara_izq);
camara_v.addView(mCamaraV);

camara_v2 = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camara_dcha);
camara_v2.addView(mCamaraV);
```

Comment: Como determinas esto David, si no sabes que realiza la clase CamaraView?

Comment: Ya lo intentaste? Y si lo intentaste, funciono?

Comment: Por lo que @MABM explica, el quiere que lo que capture la cámara se muestre en dos vistas diferentes. Y si el objeto de CameraView es el que captura la cámara, el solo tiene que pasarlo a las diferentes vistas donde quiere que se muestre. Es como que tengas un String y quieras mostrarlo en dos TextView, para hacerlo solo necesitas pasar el mismo String a los dos TextView.

Comment: He probado esto, puede mostrar illegalStateException porque usa la misma vista mCamaraV , sin embargo otro problema es el hardware, si CamaraView accede a la misma camara, solo una puede estar activa. :(

Comment: Ya lo había probado así, pero no funciona.